# regex to match content not containing multiple sentences including line breaks

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match content that does *not* include three separate sentences including line breaks.

```
one sentence
another one
last one
```

I tried this:

`^((?!this sentence|another one|last one).)*$`

which works but only along a single line, how can I make it match across multiple line breaks? It should match something like this:

```
None of the sentences
are included in this
paragraph, so it should
match the whole content
```

Comment: Maybe this can do the job `^((?!this sentence|another one|last one)(?:.|\n)*)`

Comment: Blah, that was close but it still matches the paragraph even if one of the sentences is included. I'm guessing the dot character `.` allows it to match.

Comment: Check this `^(((?!this sentence|another one|last one)(?:.|\n))*)$`

Comment: I give it as answer than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you looking for `^(((?!this sentence|another one|last one)(?:.|\n))*)$`.

Answer (score 1):

You could match all the lines that do not start with any of the options using a negative lookahead.

```
^(?:(?!this sentence|another one|last one).*\r?\n)*(?!this sentence|another one|last one).*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!this sentence|another one|last one)` Assert non of the options
  - `.*\r?\n`
- `)*` Close group and match 0+ times
- `(?!this sentence|another one|last one)` Assert non of the options
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxstJH/1)